# Value of type 'CustomObject' does not conform toe expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject'

Tags: swift, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I am transferring data from my iOS app to its Watch extension via the application context. I want to send a custom object I've created (named **WeatherReport**).

```
let context = ["report" : WeatherReport]
WCSession.defaultSession().updateApplicationContext(context)
```

However, I get the following error:

> Value of type **WeatherReport** does not conform toe expected dictionary
>   value type 'AnyObject'

I am wondering why I am unable to set my custom object as a value in the dictionary I am trying to pass as the applicationContext.

Comment: What is `WeatherReport`? Is it a `struct`?

Comment: @luk2302 It's just a custom class (not a struct), created from an empty Swift file

Comment: @luk2302 Ah, on second look it is actually struct! I assumed it wasn't because I often just go with classes. That seems to solve it. Thanks

Comment: It's because it was a struct and not a class. Using a class solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could get past the compiler error you would get a runtime error. WCSession dictionaries can only contain [property list types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html), which are just basic types such as strings, numbers, data, etc.

If you really want to send your custom object you'll have to serialize it first. The better solution is likely to convert your object in to a plist dictionary (each property becomes a key-value in the dictionary).